# JS - Datepicker width dialog

Tags: javascript

i did one datepicker that open a dialog when i hover the days.

My code:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog"><p>Nenhum evento cadastrado.</p></div>
<div id="calendario"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#calendario').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'd-m-yy',
                inline: true,
                //nextText: '&rarr;',
                //prevText: '&larr;',
                showOtherMonths: true,
                //dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
                dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb'],
                monthNames: [ "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril",
                   "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro",
                   "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro" ],
                //showOn: "button",
                //buttonImage: "img/calendar-blue.png",
                //buttonImageOnly: true,
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                    window.location = 'http://localhost/intranet/agenda.html?dt=' + dateText;
                },

            });
            $(document).on('mouseenter', 'td[data-handler="selectDay"]', function() {

                var months = [ "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro" ];

                var day   = $(this).text();
                var month =  months[$(this).data('month')];
                var year  = $(this).data('year');

                var data = day + ' de ' + month + ' de ' + year;


                $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', data);
            })



            var dialog = $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                show: { effect: "fade", duration: 150 },
                hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 150 },
                closeOnEscape:false
            });    


            $("#calendario td a").mouseover(function() {
              dialog.dialog("open");
            }).mousemove(function(event) {
              dialog.dialog("option", "position", {
                my: "left+10 top+10",
                of: event,
              });
            }).mouseout(function() {
                dialog.dialog("close");
            });


        });
```

It works perfectly in the actual month, but when i change it, dialogs don't appear anymore :(
I have no ideia why it don't go... Can anyone help me?

I did one jsfiddle example...
http://jsfiddle.net/gui5711/b44fmdjj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the setTimeout when you change the month:

```
onChangeMonthYear: function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){   
       OutrosMeses();
    });
}

.change(function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){   
        OutrosMeses();
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gui5711/b44fmdjj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your code firstly calls the jQuery function datepicker, which puts the calendar (a table with 'a' elements) in the document. After that, you assign all 'a' elements (#calendario td a) an event to show the dialog when they are hovered.

**When the month is changed, the calendar is re-written. The 'a' elements are new, so, they won't have any event attached.**

The solution would be, when the calendar month is changed, to attach events again.